# Database Function giving an error - Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, debian

I had some help on here and got the following code:

```
-- Setup Solrid Function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION solrid(IN local_id INTEGER, OUT result TEXT) AS $$
DECLARE
  database_id TEXT := 'A';
BEGIN
  result := database_id || local_id::TEXT;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

However when I run it in sqlfiddle it says:

> Schema Creation Failed: ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or
>   near "$$ DECLARE   database_id TEXT := 'A'":

This error may seem pretty self explanatory but I can't figure out the way to fix it. Would anyone mind shedding some light on this please?

Comment: Interesting, works just fine on my local db (postgresql 9.1)

Comment: Maybe its a bug with sqlfiddle? I've tried it with a few different versions and it throws up the same error each time.

Comment: Start by providing the version number you use and how you execute the code.

Comment: Sorry Jimmy, this is a confusing part of SQL Fiddle.  The problem is that your semi-colon within your function body is breaking my default parsing mechanism.  If you change your "query terminator" to something other than a semi-colon (the default) your function will work fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/ede11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with this function, it is 100 % legit. I tested with 8.4 and 9.1 in my installation.

There must be some kind of misunderstanding. This cannot be exactly the same code that triggers the error message.

Comment: If you uncomment the function at the bottom and build schema it gives the error. I think based on what you say it is a bug with the website: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/6810d

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Actually, SQL Fiddle does support functions.  You just have to change the "query terminator" to something other than a semi-colon. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/ede11

Comment: @JakeFeasel: That's awesome! I didn't know that. Deleted my incorrect comment. Would be great, of course, if the query terminator thingy could be fixed somehow, too.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes, it's a feature that I've long thought about how to improve its visibility.  Clearly a UX fail.  I have some ideas about how to improve it that I'm hoping to get around to trying out soon.