# Postgres trigger syntax

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, triggers, plpgsql

Using SQLFiddle, PostgreSQL 9.3.1.

I am learning to define triggers in PostgreSQL, and after doing some research I've found out the following:

Triggers in Postgres are different from MYSQL. Where in Postgres you must create a function that `RETURNS TRIGGER`, in MySQL you can just create a trigger. So this is what I've come up with:

On Employee Insert, we want to update Departments Total Salary.

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_sal() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.dno IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE Department SET Total_sal = total_sal  + NEW.salary
    WHERE department.dno = NEW.dno;
  END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ Language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER updateInsert
AFTER INSERT ON Employee
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_sal();
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Schema Creation Failed: ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ 
BEGIN IF NEW.dno IS NOT NULL THEN UPDATE Department 
SET Total_sal = total_sal +NEW.salary WHERE department.dno = NEW.dno":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue thanks to [Database Function giving an error - Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711103/database-function-giving-an-error-postgresql)

It seems just changing the query terminator at the bottom of the Scheme Window solves this issue.

Comment: [Related answer with more details and demo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747225/exceptions-when-creating-a-trigger-in-postgresql-9-1/22748778#22748778).

Answer (score 0):

If you copy-pasted the code, then you've got a simple syntax error: `ENDl` should be `END;` in the last-but-one line of the function definition.

Otherwise, it looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Christof, however even with the END; changed I am still getting the same error.